# Entity Framework returns 0 rows, when the same SQL command returns many rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a model (M) that contains two tables(A and B). When I run the code from my MVC application to get the rows from (A) like this:

```
var context =new ClaimsHistorical();
context.CommandTimeout = 120;
IList<ClaimsSLAMonth> list = context.ClaimsSLAMonths.Where(x=>x.timeperiod == "2012-03").ToList();
var final = list.Select(c => new[]{
            c.branch.ToString().Trim(), c.NLPR_SLA.ToString() ?? null, c.NLPR_count.ToString() ?? null, c.NLPR_AvgLocktime.ToString() ?? null, c.NLPR_PIn.ToString() ?? null, c.NLPR_POut.ToString() ?? null,
            c.NLGA_SLA.ToString() ?? null, c.NLGA_count.ToString() ?? null, c.NLGA_AvgLocktime.ToString() ?? null, c.NLGA_PIn.ToString() ?? null, c.NLGA_POut.ToString() ?? null
        });
```

When I set a breakpoint for the list.Select to check the command it gives me the SQL which works in SSMS

It returns 0 rows (no errors, warnings, messages). I copied the SQL query that is being "executed" by the EF and pasted it to SQL Server Management Studio, it returns me the 5 or so rows.

Also when I run the exact same code except I substitute the table name to (B) I get the rows correctly. I tried to recreate the Model and it still returns nothing. Am I missing something obvious, or is there something seriously wrong?

Comment: You said you took the SQL that EF "executed", so you ran the SQL profiler, copied the generated SQL statement, and ran it in SSMS? Correct?

Comment: What @M.Babcock means is did you use the actual statement from SQL Profiler, or did you use the statement displayed by the debugger when you examine the query?

Comment: Yep. Put a breakpoint at the moment it was selecting stuff, looked at the object properties (where it has the connection string and the command string) copied it to SSMS and it gave me the rows i wanted.

Comment: What's your datatype?  I'm wondering if your data might be padded (like you used a char datatype) so the exact compare fails.  Maybe try a .Startswith()

Comment: @m4tt1mus Same thing 0 rows....

Comment: @MarkPeters I'm not sure what you mean exactly, I used the Update Model and selected the Table from SQL Server and it created the Model automagically. I didn't change any of the datatypes for the columns. Also to make sure i just did context.ClaimsSLAMonths.ToList(); and 0 Rows.

Comment: I'm asking about the SQL datatype of your timeperiod column.  If it is type 'char', you might have space padded data that SSMS will match by default, but EF does not.

Comment: @MarkPeters in DB it is varchar and in the model it is mapped to be a string (Is that what you wanted to know) ?

Comment: what's timeperiod? type (EF and SQL) - does that 'where' part return something, cut everything else off. Maybe something around the dates

Comment: @NSGaga In SQL it is VARCHAR in EF it is string. Where returns nothing in EF it returns 5 rows if i run the equivalent sql code or even the one used by EF. If i take of the Where clause, it still returns nothing and it should return at least 20 rows.

Comment: you need to check your model then, something's seriously wrong there I think, if you can't get `context.ClaimsSLAMonths` to return any rows

Comment: @NSGaga That's the thing... I simply used the "Update Model" tool to create a model of existing DB (I have done this many many times never an issue.... ) and just rename the table mapping so it is easier to read (like i always do)... It is the first time i have any issues with it... I also tried recreating the model multiple times and stuff....

Comment: just a sanity check. You are looking at the same database/server?

Comment: @MarkPeters Yeah triple checked. And I "fixed" it. I still have no idea what it was/is, but after I rebooted the machine it works fine. Without changing a single line of code... Any Ideas why that would happen, or if there is some cache i can disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently rebooting the computer fixed the problem?

If anyone has any possible reasons for this (caches, settings, anything) that would help in preventing this from happening again.

Comment: Is there another way to do this that you know off?